# How do I insert a <BR> before and after a DIV with a given id with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

have been trying to do this using jQuery or even just plain javascript

This is the JS I am using:

To Hide the div:
     `$( '#HiddenGroup' ).prev('BR').remove();`

```
document.getElementById("HiddenGroup").className += ' hideDiv';
```

To redisplay the div:

```
$( 'BR' ).insertBefore('#HiddenGroup');


document.getElementById("HiddenGroup").className = document.getElementById("HiddenGroup").className.replace( / hideDiv/g , '' );



br />
    div id="HiddenGroup">div  id="Line0""> Some stuff here /div>
/div>
```

I can hide the div fine but when I try and redisplay it I get BR's being added all over the show.  Tried to add < before most of the tags in this code and it formats it as HTML...

Comment: You should use `.addClass` and `.removeClass` instead. That said, please fix your code in your question - the HTML is completely broken.

Comment: I think I'm missing the point. Why are you dealing with br's ... for spacing? Use css instead!

Comment: HTML Code I had to break as I had difficulties posting and getting the form to accept on stackoverflow so I removed some special characters.  I have used your suggestion of .addClass and .removeClass and its much better, its a legacy system so improving as I go!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
$('<br />').insertBefore('#HiddenGroup');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#HiddenGroup' ).prev('BR').remove();
```

What you are doing here is not hiding the element, but removing it from the HTML. What you can do is set the style with jQuery.

```
$( '#HiddenGroup' ).prev('BR').css('display','none');
```

And if I may suggest, you should avoid the usage of `<br>`. I believe there are a lot of other solutions that might work with your case.